# YUYV/YUV422 in image_transport

Tags: ros, opencv, vision-opencv, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most of USB webcams used in hobby robotics support YUYV coding natively. Currently both OpenCV and ROS by default convert this image to BGR format and this is not most efficient decicion for most problems. I wrote about it also into OpenCV list:

http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/HSV-image-input-YUYV-image-transport-td6246826.html

Is there are options to keep YUYV image somehow "raw" in image_transport or can new imaeg encoding added to ROS? What is your opinion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9683/yuyv/yuv422-in-image_transport/) by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2011-04-09

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-04-10**:
To do this sort of thing someone needs to put it through the REP process.  The best people to do this are people who have an unmet use case.  http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0000.html  I suggest you take a look, it's not too hard to write a REP and you'll get lots of feedback on the list.

**Comment by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on 2011-04-10**:
I see now related work in camera_umd repository file uvc_cam.cpp. So all we need is standardize YUV422 in ROS. Hey people from WillowGarage, are you listening?

**Comment by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on 2011-04-10**:
I think I do not wait until others make decicion but write new node. This node attach V4L2 camera, read YUYV image and publish it as three monochrome images on ROS. So anyone can subscribe to BW topic only or take colour channels too. This is fast, efficient and elegant.

**Comment by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on 2011-04-09**:
Most used cameras and their encodings: PS3 Eye - YUV422 only, Logitech Quickcam Pro 9000 - YUV422 (plus MJPEG, RGB3, BGR3, YU12, YV12), Logitech C910 - YUV422 (plus MJPEG). I see YUV422 is the only and right choice. Those are best and cheap webcams for robotics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd think adding the most standard YUV encodings (how many YUV encodings are there?) to sensor_msgs so that they could be used for the "encoding" field of [sensor_msgs/Image](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) would be good. That should let you essentially "pass-through" the YUYV image to another node while maintaining encoding information.

This wouldn't help with code that operates on BGR images (aka basically all of OpenCV) or likely things like image_view, so any inclusion of YUYV into sensor_msgs as a valid encoding might also want to include conversion functions between YUV encoding and BGR encoding (conversion helpers might be better placed somewhere in the image_pipeline).

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) on 2011-04-13**:
I'm in favor. Also PrimeSense devices produce YUV422, so we already have some conversion code in the openni_kinect driver that should go into OpenCV instead. As Tully said, someone needs to draft an REP stating exactly what the new encodings are, and how they should be supported in e.g. cv_bridge.

**Comment by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on 2011-04-09**:
Seems YUV422 is only one we need.